# TikZ, resizing and fitting

Tags: latex, image-resizing, tikz

I want to take a PGF picture, scale it down (scaling the text as well, so `\resizebox` would be perfect) to obtain a certain height, then put a rotated text on the left of the picture and create a node containing everything.

Something like this:

[image: Algorithm example]

But I want to be able to set the height for the chart without scaling down the rotated "title".

Here is the LaTeX code for this example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  inner sep=2mm,
    delimiter/.style={ellipse, very thick, fill=red!30, draw=red!50},
    action/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60, thick, fill=blue!30, draw=blue!50, align=center},
    loop/.style={ellipse, thick, fill=yellow!30, draw=yellow!50, align=center},
  title/.style={font=\LARGE\scshape,node distance=16pt, text=black!40, inner sep=1mm},
  background/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, fill=black!5, draw=black!15, inner sep=4mm}
]

  \node[delimiter] (begin) {Begin};
  \node[action] (cluster residues) [below=of begin] {Cluster residues};
  \node[action] (set clusters) [below=of cluster residues] {Set properties\\for every cluster};
  \node[action] (find pockets) [below=of set clusters] {Find clusters with\\$normalized\ SAS < 1$};
  \node[action] (sort pockets) [below=of find pockets] {Sort pockets found};
  \node[delimiter] (end) [below=of sort pockets] {End};

  \draw[->] (begin.south) -- (cluster residues);
  \draw[->] (cluster residues) -- (set clusters);
  \draw[->] (set clusters) -- (find pockets);
  \draw[->] (find pockets) -- (sort pockets);
  \draw[->] (sort pockets) -- (end);

  \node[fit=(begin)(cluster residues)(set clusters)(find pockets)(sort pockets)(end)] (chart) {};
  \node[title] (title) [left=of chart] {\rotatebox{90}{General algorithm}};

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[background,fit=(chart)(title)] {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to use `\resizebox`, `\adjustbox` or anything else to resize *only* the chart (not the "General algorithm" label)?

Answer (score 7):

You can put the chart into a `scope` and use the `scale` option to resize it. Notice the `transform shape` option. See the pgfmanual (17.7 Transformations) for details.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  inner sep=2mm,
    delimiter/.style={ellipse, very thick, fill=red!30, draw=red!50},
    action/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60, thick, fill=blue!30, draw=blue!50, align=center},
    loop/.style={ellipse, thick, fill=yellow!30, draw=yellow!50, align=center},
  title/.style={font=\LARGE\scshape,node distance=16pt, text=black!40, inner sep=1mm},
  background/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, fill=black!5, draw=black!15, inner sep=4mm}
]

  \begin{scope}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
      \node[delimiter] (begin) {Begin};
      \node[action] (cluster residues) [below=of begin] {Cluster residues};
      \node[action] (set clusters) [below=of cluster residues] {Set properties\\for every cluster};
      \node[action] (find pockets) [below=of set clusters] {Find clusters with\\$normalized\ SAS < 1$};
      \node[action] (sort pockets) [below=of find pockets] {Sort pockets found};
      \node[delimiter] (end) [below=of sort pockets] {End};

      \draw[->] (begin.south) -- (cluster residues);
      \draw[->] (cluster residues) -- (set clusters);
      \draw[->] (set clusters) -- (find pockets);
      \draw[->] (find pockets) -- (sort pockets);
      \draw[->] (sort pockets) -- (end);
  \end{scope}

  \node[fit=(begin)(cluster residues)(set clusters)(find pockets)(sort pockets)(end)] (chart) {};
  \node[title] (title) [left=of chart] {\rotatebox{90}{General algorithm}};

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[background,fit=(chart)(title)] {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know that I can scale scopes and pictures, but, as I said, I need to set the final height. I _could_ calculate the ratio by myself, but it is not an optimal solution, especially if I need to make many changes.